# Detecting changes in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

I'm developing an app with CodeIgniter and I want to detect when some elements in the DOM has changed. Suppose I have the following:

```
<input type="text" name="idPerson0" id="idPerson" value="<?= $idPerson0; ?>"  style="width: 150px;"/>
<input type="text" name="idPerson1" id="idPerson1" value="<?= $idPerson2; ?>"  style="width: 150px;"/>
<input type="text" name="idPerson2" id="idPerson2" value="<?= $idPerson2; ?>"  style="width: 150px;"/>
```

`$idPerson0, $idPerson1, $idPerson2` are set. Then I want to display a tooltip when anyone change, showing the original value, but if I decide to put the original value again, the tooltip belonging to the appropiate input should dissapear.

Currently, I'm working with JQuery but with a button "Verify".

```
$('#btn-verify').click(function () {
    var old_id0 = "<?= $idPersona0 ?>";
    var old_id1 = "<?= $idPersona1 ?>";
    var old_id2 = "<?= $idPersona2 ?>";


    var new_id0 = $("#idPersona0").val();
    var new_id1 = $("#idPersona1").val();
    var new_id2 = $("#idPersona2").val();

    if (old_id0 != new_id0){
        // show tooltip
    } else {
       // hide tooltip
    }

    // the other ifs
}
```

I suppose there is a "real time way" to display tooltips and check differences.

Comment: 'change' event bound to the inputs? And keep the names in an object outside the change function so you can compare new values with old values.

Answer (score 2):

You could fire that function on the change event, in jquery:

```
$("#idPerson0,#idPerson1,#idPerson2").change(function(){
    var old_id0 = "<?= $idPersona0 ?>";
    var old_id1 = "<?= $idPersona1 ?>";
    var old_id2 = "<?= $idPersona2 ?>";


    var new_id0 = $("#idPersona0").val();
    var new_id1 = $("#idPersona1").val();
    var new_id2 = $("#idPersona2").val();

    if (old_id0 != new_id0){
        // show tooltip
    } else {
       // hide tooltip
    }

    // the other ifs
}
```

Comment: @Shilly answered it in a different way, thank you!